# How can I read m3u8 format video stream and save it with opencv in python?

Tags: python, opencv, stream, m3u8, timelapse

I'm trying to save video stream, and to timelapse it. I know how to read any video from computer (for example mp4 format) and make a timelapse (I tried, I succeeded). Now I'm trying to do the same with a video stream.
I have link for m3u8 video https://wstream.comanet.cz:1943/live/Vrchlabi-sjezdovka2.stream_360p/playlist.m3u8, I'm reading video like this:
(Initialization:)

```
import cv2 as cv
url = 'https://wstream.comanet.cz:1943/live/Vrchlabi-sjezdovka2.stream_360p/playlist.m3u8'
fourcc = cv.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
height = video.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
width = video.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
outp = cv.VideoWriter(save_path, fourcc, 60,(int(width), int(height)))
video = cv.VideoCapture("url")

dir_stream = "streamframes"

if not os.path.exists(dir_stream):
    os.makedirs(dir_stream)

if not video.isOpened():
    print("Error opening video file.")
```

(There is a main part - loop:)

```
name = 0
while video.isOpened():
    ret, frame = video.read()
        name += 1
        filename = f"{dir_stream}/{name}.jpg"
        cv.imwrite(filename, frame)
        f = cv.imread(filename)
        outp.write(f)
```

I don't like the way of saving the video... anyway - it's not completely wrong... it kind of works, but after few read frames (sometimes it's 153, 212 etc), `ret` value is returning `False` value and code gets into infinite loop. After I stopped the program, my video was saved and I could play it, it was just short (cause it was not recording as long as I wanted, because of infinite loop)...

In the "while" part I also tried...:

```
while video.isOpened():
        ret, frame = video.read()
        if ret:
            frame_r = cv.imread(frame)
            outp.write(frame_r)
```

... it's much more nice, but `cv.imread(frame)` was not working so I did it in dirty way u can see above.

**My goal is recording online stream with python for some time (e.g. for 5 hours), I don't need record with 30fps, (e.g. 1fps is also fine).**
Can anyone help me with this problem? Or do you have some advice? Why `ret` value returns False after some random time? Do you have other solution? I'll be really thankful for your help, it's for my school project.